# How to use custom view in iOS with auto layout?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, autolayout

I want to use custom view in my iOS app, and so I put some UI components on the xib of the custom view and add some autolayout constraints to it, and ran the simulator, the result is fine.

However, I don't like to make the custom view cover the whole window and rather I want to make it cover only some part of the window. So I changed its size from within the code, such as:

```
let detailView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DetailTaskView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as DetailTaskView
detailView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 80, 280, 280)
```

However, then the resultant custom view is fine in terms of the size, but the components there are not aligned properly. Especially, despite the fact that I added top constraints (8px) to the `UILabel` and the bottom constraints (8px) to `UIButton` (as well as the horizontal constraints to both components), the resultant custom view doesn't show `UIButton`, on which it looks like the only top part of the custom view is taken off instead of the middle portion is chopped off.

So how can I use the custom view with the custom size?

#### UPDATE

Here's my custom view looks like:

```
[label]
--empty--
[button]
```

What I want to show is the following:

```
[label]
[button]
// the empty part on the middle is chopped off in 4inch iPhone
```

However, here's the result I got:

```
[label]
--empty--
// and the button on the bottom is chopped off
```

Comment: What you say you did should have worked if you also have the correct horizontal constraints. What horizontal constraints do you have?

Comment: @rdelmar, I added horizontal constraints but I think it is not related to the issue. But updated the original post.

Comment: If the button has a bottom constraint of 8 to the bottom of the view, this shouldn't be happening. Are there any other vertical constraints on the button?

Comment: I found that the issue came from that my label's height was too big (or high? large?) that it prevents the button from being shown on the view. Thanks, @rdelmar.

Answer (score -2):

Is your xib's main view set to 280x280 pixels? If so, then whatever constraints you set should hold--in other words, if your label and button fit in the 280x280 xib, then they should show up properly at runtime. It may also help to set a vertical spacing constraint between the bottom of the label and the top of the button. Also ensure that whatever view your custom view is contained in isn't setting the custom view's size to something other than what you expect.